# How to take a screenshot with the video picture in iOS?

Tags: ios, screenshot

AVPlayer is repeating play a small video in the middle of viewController.

the viewController have a bottomView and a topView, and I use the following method to capture a screenshot

```
func getScreenshotImage() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size)
    self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return viewImage
}

func getScreenshotImage() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(window().bounds.size)
    window().layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return viewImage
}
```

These two methods have the same effect , they can capture the topView and bottomView , but the midpoints of the screen is black.

What can I do to capture the shot with a video screen just like the iPhone effect while pressing the power button and home button

Thanks in advance！